# How to draw Crescent Moon shape on a circle

Tags: android, canvas, shapes

I want to create a shape like this on a canvas. I know how to draw a circle with a stroke but I want a crescent moon kind of an effect on the circle.

[image]

Here is the code of the circle:

```
          Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        float mid1;
        float min1,fat1,half1,rad1;

            mid1 = ImageWidth / 2;
            min1 = Math.min(ImageWidth, ImageHeight);
            fat1 = min1 / 17;
            half1 = min1 / 2;
            rad1 = half1 - fat1;
            mid1 = mid1 - half1;

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(mid1 + half1, half1, rad1, paint);
```

The code is working perfectly for the circle. I know how to draw a stroke too but I cant create a crescent moon effect.

Answer (score 2):

Set a circular [clip path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipPath(android.graphics.Path)) and then draw a second circle displaced by some quantity in both x and y.

Answer (score 0):

[image: pic]

You can refer to this [view](https://github.com/zhangchaojiong/VideoProgressView)，Use Bezier curve to draw, use PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT to get the correct partial view (moon view).